# Casting performance in Java

Tags: java, performance, casting

I've a Servlet filter which performs the following type cast:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
```

At present my filter is responsible for two tasks that would be better separated into two filters. If I'd split the logic into two filters I'd need two casts.

What is the performance impact of such a cast? Is it worth to accept this performance degradation for a better architecture?

Comment: always avoid and use tostring or likewise instead

Comment: A String would not be helpful if I need to call methods on HttpServletRequest. And why should a prefer toString and the like over casting?

Comment: @deamon: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170872/does-java-casting-introduce-overhead-why Tom Hawtin's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the performance impact of such
>   a cast?

As compared to *handling a HTTP request*? Absolutely none. If you were doing it in a deeply nested loop that does little else it might matter, but not when it's done once for a task that involves things that are literally *millions* of times more work (like doing DB requests or accessing the harddisk).

Answer (score 5):

Performance impact will be negligible (compared to the total work done). Java does **a lot** of casting, like in the collection framework, hence the engineers already optimized it well. An additional casting won't change much, besides, readability (maintainability?) is more important.

Comment: Do you have a link and/or reference for that, please?

Comment: @DerMike I forgot, sorry. In the meantime, feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The cast has almost no performance impact. (**Edited**, thanks to commentors)

As long as you have no real performance problem, always go for better architecture.

Comment: Your first statemet is absolutely wrong. A cast in Java involves runtime work - at the very least the JVM has to check if the object is in fact of the required type so that it can throw a ClassCastException when it's not.

Comment: Casts in Java can be optimized away in special cases by the compiler - but in most cases, such as this, it does involve runtime work. So, there is a performance impact, even if not especially relevant in this case.