# Casting performance in different levels when casting down

Tags: java, android, dalvik

Lets assume we have three (or more) classes

public class A {}

public class B extends A {}

public class C extends B implements G {}

Assume each class has its own 20 (or more) methods.

Is casting to C vs casting to A has larger impact on performance? How does Java casting work under the hood?

Does it have to check for all methods and fields for presence by reflection when casting down?

**Edit:**
Does the size of classes (number of fields and methods) impacts the performance when casting?
I'm interested in both **OpenJRE** and **Dalvik**.

For the reference, I know that upcasting can be done with no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance of the casting depends on the JVM implementation.

The [JLS 5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5) only determines the requirements for the casting (which includes a recursive algorithm), but does not set any requirements upon the implementation. Actually the [runtime cast rules in 5.5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.3) are also determined the same way. All JVM implementations that produce th same result as the proposed algorithm are accepted as a proper JVM.

Generally, casting down to `C` takes a little bit more time since the JVM must examine the runtime type of the object. When casting up to `A` it has no reason to do the same check, since `B` extends `A`.

Actually, the JVM does not care about the number of methods and fields. It only compares the type hierarchy, the same you can examine with reflection (`o.getClass()`)

I made a sample code as follows, one downcast, then an upcast:

```
Object o = new Integer(1);
Integer i = (Integer) o;

Object o2 = i;
```

The compiled bytecode is the following:

```
 0  new java.lang.Integer [16]
 3  dup
 4  iconst_1       <-- 1 as a parameter to the constructor
 5  invokespecial java.lang.Integer(int) [18]   <-- constructor
 8  astore_1 [o]       <-- store in 'o'
 9  aload_1 [o]
10  checkcast java.lang.Integer [16]    <-- DOWNCAST CHECK, SPECIAL BYTECODE
13  astore_2 [i]
14  aload_2 [i]
15  astore_3 [o2]   <-- WITH UPCAST NO CHECK
```

So, there is a specific JVM instruction that checks the element on the top of the stack with a given class.

With upcast, there is no check at all.

The size of the classes (number of fields, methods, actual footprint) **does not matter**, because the casting examines the `Class` (the metadata, which is actually an object).

The number of hierarchy levels, and the number if implemented interfaces (if casting to an interface) **does matter**, because that is the traversable inheritance/implementation tree to check.

I would be surprised if there wouldn't be some kind of **cache** for this check.

Comment: "since the JVM must examine the runtime type of the object" how does it examine?

Comment: Thanks, would be great if you could tell me in short words what kind of operations does isAssignableForm do? It's difficult to analyze this kind of source code.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, the truth is even more native than `isAssignableFrom()`

Comment: "With downcast, there is no check at all". You call cast from Integer to Object "downcasting"? I thought it was upcasting.
But the answer is still not very clear for me. Does it take more performance when casting down through Object -> A -> B -> C rather than from Object -> A ?

Comment: Updated the quetion a bit.

Comment: So, if you are curious about the `check-cast` internals, maybe try to google it (I couldn't find any relevant result). I suppose that the search is done through the type hierarchy (extension and implementation) of the *casted object runtime class* upwards. The difference can be some processor cycles, but since it is native code, I don't think it would be relevant.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait some time for others to answer before accepting this answer.

Comment: `check-cast` calls `dvmInstanceOf()`, which does a cache lookup.  Last time I checked the hit rate was > 95% for framework code.  So for the most part the effects of class depth won't be noticeable.

Comment: @fadden Thanks for sharing the info. Do you have some reference for it or some other way to check how it works?

Comment: Just the sources.  Start with `dalvik/vm/mterp/c/OP_CHECK_CAST.cpp` to see where it begins.  The cache, checked in `dvmInstanceofNonTrivial()` in `dalvik/vm/oo/TypeCheck.cpp`, is implemented with some macro fun; see `dalvik/vm/AtomicCache.h` and `.cpp`.  If it misses, you end up in `isInstanceof()`, which then splits out depending on whether you're checking vs. an interface, array, or class.  For interfaces it does a linear walk through the "flattened" list of interfaces, for classes it does a recursive walk up the tree.

Answer (score 2):

For a detailed architecture of `checkcast` (which was mentioned in other response as a JVM mechanism for downcasting) in HotSpot, take a look at this conference paper:

[Fast subtype checking in the HotSpot JVM](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221552851_Fast_subtype_checking_in_the_HotSpot_JVM)

A quote from the abstract:

> In actual benchmark runs our technique performs complete subtype
>   checks in 3 instructions (only 1 memory reference) essentially all the
>   time. In rare instances it reverts to a slower array scan. Memory
>   usage is moderate (6 words per class) and can be traded off for time.

So if you don't write some very low-level code with a lot of casting, the impact is negligible.