# Is using a generic FindViewById a bad practice?

Tags: android

**Situation** 
I have a BaseActivity from which I extend other activities. In the **BaseActivity** I have a `findCastedViewById` which basicaly casts the view and then returns it. 
I do this because I, personaly, find it ugly casting the view all the time.

**Question** 
I was wondering if there is any **problem** or **cons** that I could get from using this approach that anybody else using this method had. 

Here is BaseActivity:

### BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{

  //Other stuff

  private <E extends View> E findCastedViewById(int id){
          return (E) findViewById(id);
  }

  //Other stuff
}
```

Comment: not really but you could save a lot of time and improve readability by using http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/ Check it out

Comment: Nice question never though about that. If someone has an answer I would gladly read it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lukaspp already noted, in SDK 26+ there is no need for vew casting.

They have implemented the same code as in the question, except it is now the default `findViewById()`. So yes OP, your code is good!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 4):

Consider using **ButterKnife**, it solves the problem of having to continuously **cast** your views and it saves you a lot of time

Once you go **butterknife**, there's no way back

Basically you annotate the View variables with

**@FindView** annotation and it will find the correct view for you when **ButterKnife.bind(this)** is called

Here's a small snippet of code where ButterKnife is used from the GitHub Page

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @FindView(R.id.user) EditText username;
  @FindView(R.id.pass) EditText password;

  @OnClick(R.id.submit) void submit() {
    // TODO call server...
  }

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Use fields...
  }
}
```

You can read more about **ButterKnife** from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

Comment: I just had a quick look at ButterKnife and yes it is very useful and basically solves the problem very well so +1 for you but this is not the answer I was looking for, I was wondering the cons of the method I was using!

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902651/no-need-to-cast-the-result-of-findviewbyid), if you `compileSdk` is at least API 26, you don't need to cast the view anymore.

Answer (score -3):

It's not only *ugly* but also an expensive operation if you repeat it constantly.

If you are sure you will always need that specific derived class, you can freely use it. However, I sometimes find I only need methods from the base class `View`, e.g. `setVisibility()`, in such occasions casting would be a waste.

Comment: Can you please update the answer and explain why it would be an expensive operation?

Comment: @Assa this is common java knowledge and it was [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170872/does-java-casting-introduce-overhead-why) before.

Comment: So if I got it right my method can be expensive because of the castings?

Comment: First, read a comment accessible by the link: this is old information, casts are faster now.
Second, the problem is not in generic findView, but in using concrete types. The question is about the situation when vague types cannot be used, so the answer is wrong.