# Hibernate 5.2 version -> A lot of Query methods deprecate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, dao

I'm new to Hibernate.

I'm trying to get a list of first name and last name of all administrators.

There are two warnings in my following code. I already tried to search a lot online.

1) Query is a raw type. References to generic type Query should be parameterized.

2) The method list() from the type Query is deprecated.

```
public List<Object> loadAllAdmins() {
                List<Object> allAdmins = new ArrayList<Object>();
                try {
                        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();

                        Query q = currentSession.createQuery("SELECT admin.firstName, admin.lastName from AdminBean admin");

                        allAdmins= q.list();

                        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
                } catch (HibernateException ex) {
                        System.out.println("List<AdminBean> loadAllPersons: HibernateException");
                }
                return allAdmins;
        }
```

But I see sample code like this all over the web. How should I solve these two problems?

**Update**

I just tried to use Criteria as suggested. It also says the list() method is deprecate for Criteria... It seems that a lot of methods are deprecate for both Query and Criteria, including uniqueResult() and others... Any suggestion how I should replace them?

Comment: Maybe inspect given class in JavaDoc, there can be a suggestion - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String- .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public List<Admin> getAdmins() {
    List<Admin> AdminList = new ArrayList<Admin>(); 
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    for (Object oneObject : session.createQuery("FROM Admin").getResultList()) {
        AdminList.add((Admin)oneObject);
    }
    session.close();
    return AdminList;
}
```

The warnings came from "Type Inference".

I had the similar problem. However, I found a solution without "SuppressWarnings".

---

Recently, I found out a shorter way to code the same things without type inference.

```
public List<Admin> getAdmins() {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    TypedQuery<Admin> query = session.createQuery("FROM Admin");
    List<Admin> result = query.getResultList();
    session.close();
    return result;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems to be the same procedure as stated in my answer with the exception of an explicit cast isn't it ? Isn't it a runtime disadavantage to cast each object explicity (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170872/does-java-casting-introduce-overhead-why) ?

Comment: 1. No. As I stated, The suppress warning is removed. 
2. Yes, but I think it would be worth. It's usually worth trying to work out a way of avoiding the warning rather than suppressing it.

Answer (score 15):

Don't import `QUERY` from `org.hibernate` (As its Deprecated now). Instead import from “org.hibernate.query” .[Eclipse reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tljaj.png)

Answer (score 3):

I tested other methods of [hibernate javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html) and i came up with `getResultList()` method of the `TypedQuery<T>` interface. Example:

```
public List<Admin> getAdmins() {
  Session session = factory.openSession();
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<Admin> result = session.createQuery("FROM Admin").getResultList();
  session.close();
  return result;
}
```

The difference is that the returned type of `createQuery` is not `Query` but a subinterface called `TypedQuery<T>`. Because it is *typed*, it also fixes the "Query is a raw type" warning.

With this solution you may get a *Type Safety* warning, which can be solved by either casting each object explicitly or by adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Regarding criterias see [hibernate user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria)

Nevertheless, i am wondering why the tutorials-page of hibernate is not adjusted.

Comment: This method is too deprecated!

Comment: `createQuery()` is not deprecated and `getResultList()` is not deprecated.see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String-@EmilianoDueñas.

Answer (score 2):

Although late to the party but may be worth noting the overloaded createQuery method (to avoid warnings altogether):

```
public List<Admin> loadAllAdmins() {
    try {
        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
        List<Admin> admins = currentSession.createQuery("SELECT admin.firstName, admin.lastName from AdminBean admin", Admin.class).getResultList();
        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
        return admins;
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        System.out.println("List<AdminBean> loadAllPersons: HibernateException");
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Hibernate Create Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/QueryProducer.html#createSQLQuery-java.lang.String-) , there are two types of `createQuery()` methods :

> ```
> Query createQuery(java.lang.String queryString )
> ```

Create a Query instance for the given HQL/JPQL query string.

> ```
> <R> Query<R> createQuery(java.lang.String queryString,
>                          java.lang.Class<R> resultClass)
> ```

Create a typed Query instance for the given HQL/JPQL query string.

In your case you used the first `Query` and list() method is `@deperecated`.

You can user `getResultList()` instead of `list()` for Multiple results :

```
List<Object> loadAllAdmins() {
    List<Object> allAdmins = new ArrayList<Object>();
        try {
       HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();

       allAdmins= List<Object> currentSession.createQuery("SELECT admin.firstName, admin.lastName from AdminBean admin").getResultList();


                        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
                } catch (HibernateException ex) {
                        System.out.println("List<AdminBean> loadAllPersons: HibernateException");
                }
                return allAdmins;
        }
```

For single result you can use `getSingleResult()` :

```
       Admin= (Object) currentSession.createQuery("SELECT admin.firstName, admin.lastName from AdminBean admin").getSingleResult();
```

**PS:** I used `Object` based on your type `Object` ,you can cast the result according to used type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use criteria?

See that example:

```
public List<NoteVO> listNotes() {
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();

    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(NoteVO.class);

    List<NoteVO> listNotes = crit.list();

    session.close();
    return listNotes;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried. It also says the list() method is deprecate for Criteria as well... It seems that "all methods" are deprecate for both Query and Criteria, including uniqueResult() and others... I don't know why this could ever happen. I did exactly the same thing as all online tutorials.

Comment: `createCriteria()` is `@Deprecated` in Hibernate 5.2.