# What method should I use in Hibernate for delete query instead of deprecated createQuery()?

Tags: hibernate

According to documentation I have to use createQuery(String, Class), createSelectionQuery(), or createMutationQuery() instead of deprecated createQuery(String). But all of them doesn't fit.

[image: 1]

Would you tell me what exactly method shoul I use for this query? Thank you in advance.

I haven't found this information on internet.

UPD: Should I use Criteria API in this case?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460764/hibernate-5-2-version-a-lot-of-query-methods-deprecate and this one too https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/sqlquery-and-org-hibernate-query-are-deprecated-what-to-use-instead/1179

Comment: In the first case there is being used exactly createQuery that I try to workaround as deprecated, in the second there is being used createNativeQuery that although works but is deprecaed as well.

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation notice in the Javadoc actually points to `createMutationQuery`, but if you are using JPA APIs i.e. `jakarta.persistence.EntityManager`, then you can continue using that method.